# Implementing MKAnnotation protocol in Binding project

Tags: c#, objective-c, xamarin.ios, cocoa-bindings, ibeacon

Hi ma trying to create the following declaration in a iOS Binding project.
The source Objective C declaration is the following

```
@interface LeBlutrackerDevice : LeDevice <MKAnnotation>
{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D _coord;
}

@property (nonatomic,readonly,copy) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic,readonly,copy) NSString *subtitle;
@property (nonatomic,readonly) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *svInfo;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *navInfo;

@property (nonatomic,readonly) enum LE_DEVICE_STATE state;
@property (nonatomic,strong) id <LeBlutrackerDeviceDelegate> delegate;
@property (readonly) BOOL bcKeyEnabled;
- (BOOL) writeBroadcastKey: (NSData *) key;

@end
```

This is what i have in the ApiDefinition.cs

```
[Model, BaseType (typeof (LeDevice))]
public partial interface LeBlutrackerDevice : MKAnnotation
{
    [Export ("title", ArgumentSemantic.Copy)]
    string Title { get; }

    [Export ("subtitle", ArgumentSemantic.Copy)]
    string Subtitle { get; }

    [Export ("coordinate")]
    CLLocationCoordinate2D Coordinate { get; }

    [Export ("svInfo", ArgumentSemantic.Retain)]
    string SvInfo { get; set; }

    [Export ("navInfo", ArgumentSemantic.Retain)]
    string NavInfo { get; set; }

    [Export ("state")]
    LE_DEVICE_STATE State { get; }

    [Export ("delegate", ArgumentSemantic.Retain)]
    LeBlutrackerDeviceDelegate Delegate { get; set; }

    [Export ("bcKeyEnabled")]
    bool BcKeyEnabled { get; }

    [Export ("writeBroadcastKey:")]
    bool WriteBroadcastKey (NSData key);
}
```

And i get the following errors

```
Target GenerateBindings:

ApiDefinition.cs(309,48): error CS0527: Type `MonoTouch.MapKit.MKAnnotation' in interface list is not an interface

ApiDefinition.cs(313,10): warning CS0108: `SticknFind.LeBlutrackerDevice.Title' hides inherited member `MonoTouch.MapKit.MKAnnotation.Title'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended

ApiDefinition.cs(316,10): warning CS0108: `SticknFind.LeBlutrackerDevice.Subtitle' hides inherited member `MonoTouch.MapKit.MKAnnotation.Subtitle'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended

ApiDefinition.cs(319,26): warning CS0108: `SticknFind.LeBlutrackerDevice.Coordinate' hides inherited member `MonoTouch.MapKit.MKAnnotation.Coordinate'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended
```

Anyone attempting to create a binding for SticknFind SDK? please let me know since I am more than happy to post the final result on GitHub.

If I try it to inherit from IMKAnnotation i get the following error

```
btouch: No [Export] attribute on property SticknFind.LeBlutrackerDevice.Coordinate
Task "BTouch" execution -- FAILED
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to inherit from the the *interface* not the *type*, that's what causing the first CS0527 error.

It's the interface that's decorated with the `[Protocol]` attribute (so it will match the ObjC declaration). It will also solve the later CS0108 errors since the type has extra members not part of the protocol.

So this should solve it:

```
[BaseType (typeof (LeDevice))]
public partial interface LeBlutrackerDevice : IMKAnnotation {
   ...
}
```

Comment: that is not enough, when doing that I get the error about either hiding the Coordinate property or, if I remove it, that the property Coordinate is not exported. either way this ishte error i get when using the interface, Coordinate are not exported on IMKAnnotation, See the edited post

Comment: @DiegoColombo: this doesn't work due to a bug in Xamarin.iOS (https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=16948) - atm the only way to work around this is to inline the API you want from MKAnnotation in LeBlutrackerDevice yourself.

Comment: Oh so wish this fix is rear leased soon not sure about the missing properties on the IMKAnnotation anyway. It doesn't have the Title and Subtitle properties of the objective c MKAnnotation protocol